# Hadoop reuse Job object

Tags: hadoop, reset, jobs

I have a pool of Jobs from which I retrieve jobs and start them. The pattern is something like:

```
    Job job = JobPool.getJob();
    job.waitForCompletion();
    JobPool.release(job);
```

I get a problem when I try to reuse a job object in the sense that it doesn't even run (most probably because it's status is : COMPLETED). So, in the following snippet the second `waitForCompletion` call prints the statistics/counters of the job and doesn't do anything else.

```
    Job jobX = JobPool.getJob();
    jobX.waitForCompletion();
    JobPool.release(jobX);

    //.......

    Job jobX = JobPool.getJob();
    jobX.waitForCompletion(); // <--- here the job should run, but it doesn't
```

Am I right when I say that the job doesn't actually run because hadoop sees its status as completed and it doesn't event try to run it ? If yes, do you know how to reset a job object so that I can reuse it ?

Comment: why you ever need to reuse it? why not to create new object?

Comment: @octo: To avoid the overhead of job creation once an algorithm is started. 
And also to avoid creating too many jobs (even thought this can be ensured also by other means). So the first reason would the primary one. My impression is that creating a Job object and initializing it is a time consuming procedure.

Comment: i think you completely wrong. job initialization is time consuming procedure due of communication between jobtracker and you client. you can't reuse job, because each job recieves unique id

Comment: I'm talking about the job object not the job on the hadoop cluster. There is no communication involved in instantiating the job object.

Comment: object creation time is negligible relative to job startup time (even in local mode)

Comment: creating, let's say,a few hundreds/thousands objects and then garbage collecting them will certainly have an impact on the time efficiency

Comment: thousand of jobs will require more then 30 thousands seconds to initalize on real cluster. and of course, initialization of object measured in nanoseconds. here is far more expensive objects, like SimpleDateFormat, and we are still talking about nanosecods http://paste.ubuntu.com/1283595/. You can check your assumptions with http://code.google.com/p/caliper/ , very useful microbenchmark tool

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html) includes this hint that the jobs should only run once

> The set methods only work until the job is submitted, afterwards they will throw an IllegalStateException.

I think there's some confusion about the job, and the view of the job.  The latter is the thing that you have got, and it is designed to map to at most one job running in hadoop.  The view of the job is fundamentally light weight, and if creating that object is expensive relative to actually running the job... well, I've got to believe that your jobs are simple enough that you don't need hadoop.

Using the view to submit a job is potentially expensive (copying jars into the cluster, initializing the job in the JobTracker, and so on); conceptually, the idea of telling the jobtracker to "rerun " or "copy  ; run ", makes sense.  As far as I can tell, there's no support for either of those ideas in practice.  I suspect that hadoop isn't actually guaranteeing retention policies that would support either use case.